# How to hide the characters for which there are no products reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a brand listing page where the brands are displayed under each respective alphabet. Now some of the alphabets dont have any brands. How to make those not to display the alphabets. I have the below code and tried

```
    getBrands = () => {
        if(this.isBrandsAvailable()){
            return  brandList.map((key) => {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            {key}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {this.renderBrandDetails(this.getBrandsByCharacter(key))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }) 
        }
        else{
            return null
        }
    }
```

For the above component the down below image is the output

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnoh8.png)

I just want to display the characters when the brands are present under that particular category

How do I solve it?

I am expecting my page to look like this [as in link][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `brandsByCharacter` before return in `getBrands`:

```
getBrands = () => {
    if (this.isBrandsAvailable()) {
      return brandList.map((key) => {
        const brandsByCharacter = this.getBrandsByCharacter(key);
        if (brandsByCharacter?.length > 0) {
          return (
            <div>
              <div>{key}</div>
              <div>
                {this.renderBrandDetails(brandsByCharacter)}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
        return null;
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You must reduce this `brandList` into an array just with the available brands

```
getBrands = () => {
  if (this.isBrandsAvailable()) {
    return brandList.reduce((acc, key) => {
      const brand = this.getBrandsByCharacter(key);
      if (brand) {
        return [
          ...acc,
          {
            key,
            rendered: this.renderBrandDetails(brand)
          }
        ];
      }
    }, []);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: the how do I map the array elements to display it. and getting this error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, rendered}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`